# Refactor the code inside the two onClick() methods into a common method

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Sutck on  a Code Challenge on refactoring Android Code.

**Refactor the code inside the two onClick() methods into a common method named trackButtonPress(). Make it a public method of MainActivity.java.**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {        
        public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();        
        public Button mButton1;
        public Button mButton2;        
        /*
         * Some code has been omitted for brevity
         */   

       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
            mButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            mButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);        
            trackButtonPress();
        }                               
          mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
                trackButtonPress();
                }              
        }
                mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
                trackButtonPress();
                }              
        }

   public void trackButtonPress() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A button was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "A button was pressed");
                }               
            }
```

HELP PLEASE!!!

Comment: Why should we do the challenge for you? What's the challenge in that?

Comment: We are not getting the what challenge you are facing???? Looking at your code you have written method "trackButtonPress" outside the class.... Is this the challenge???

Comment: Currently, it is unclear what is the real issue stated in this question. You asked to refactor the `onClick()` methods into a common method. You posted the code, but I assume this is after you've integrate your modification which made some important information lost and made this question unaswerable. If you really want to get help, please post the original code before the modification *and* what you've done (which is the modification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each `OnClickListener` you need to override `onClick` which requires the `View` as a parameter.

In your method `trackButtonPress` you should pass the `View` parameter also.

```
public void trackButtonPress(View v) {
    // see below
}
```

Then you can test which view was clicked if you store references to your views.

```
if (v == view1) {
    // do stuff
} else if (v == view2) {
    // do other stuff
} // etc..
```

This will provide the expected functionality.